# Why do I need to remove [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

If I'll remove [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] , my code works. But I don't understand why do I need to remove  makeKeyAndVisible?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

 if (isLoginScreenNeeded)
   {    
    LoginModalViewController *controller = [[[LoginModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginModal" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *controllerNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] autorelease];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:controllerNav animated:NO];
    //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; //controllerNav didn't appeared if I uncomment this string
    }
    else
     {
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
     }

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; will immediately run after self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;